# Push something into a specified position in an array in php

Tags: php, arrays

if I give you an array:

```
$a = array('something' => 'value', 'apple' => 'sauce');
```

and said given the key, find the position and insert something before it - what would you do?

I can find something by doing:

```
function insert($value, $array)
  foreach($array as $k=>$v) {
    if ($k === $value) {
      // I am stuck here ...
    }
  }
}
```

But I don't know how to insert before `$k` in the array. This example assumes the array always has `key=>value`.

## Update 1

Apologies all, I don't think I was very clear. Given the above information the goal is to use this "insert" function  to insert a new key=>value, so given the above sample array, I want to do:

`insert(array('new_key' => 'new_value'), 'something', $a)`

So the above for loop would have to be changed to:

```
function insert($array, $key, $originalArray)
  foreach($originalArray as $k=>$v) {
    if ($k === $key) {
      // Insert $array right before 'something'
      // I am stuck here ...
    }
  }
}
```

The result would be a new array that looks like:

```
$a = array('new_key' => 'new_value', 'something' => 'value', 'apple' => 'sauce');
```

The goal is to find the key in the given array and insert the new array right before it. Both arrays must be key/value.

Comment: you can't, really. you're using a hash, and there's no guaranteed that the new key gets inserted in any particular location in the internal representation of the array. you'd have to build a new array, and put things into the new array in the proper order.

Comment: @MarcB Could you demonstrate with an example how you might achieve this?

Comment: @KyleAdams Do you mean something like this: http://3v4l.org/KXNRr ?

Comment: If people are going to down vote at least give me a reason why.

Comment: @Rizier123 I flushed out the question please revisit it, expeicially Update 1

Comment: @MarcB I flushed out the question please revisit it, expeicially Update 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a function which will insert an element into an array before or after the chosen value. It returns the modified array.

```
function associativeArrayInject($originalArray, $targetKey, $newKey, $newValue, $insertBefore=true){
    # We will build a new array from the ground up, and return it. This is that array.
    $newArray = array();

    # Loop over the original array.
    foreach($originalArray as $key => $value){
        # If we need to inject the data before the current key, we
        # do that here
        if($key === $targetKey && $insertBefore) 
            $newArray[$newKey] = $newValue;

        # At this point, we insert the $originalArray's key and value
        # because if we needed to inject before, it's already been done,
        # and if we need to inject after, we'll do that next
        $newArray[$key] = $value;

        # If we need to inject the data after the current key, we
        # do that here
        if($key === $targetKey && !$insertBefore)
            $newArray[$newKey] = $newValue;
    }

    # When all the array values are looped over, the new array will have
    # been constructed with the new data in the appropriate spot. Now
    # we can return it.
    return $newArray;
}
```

Comment: I flushed out the question please revisit it, expeicially Update 1

Comment: My function does exactly what your question asks.  

Your example in Update 1 shows you giving the key of the array to inject your data before as an argument. Give my answer a second look.

Answer (score 0):

Sol. 1: Try to use arsort() or similar functions of sorting arrays in php.

Sol. 2: At first init array of values and than use foreach loop to sort array how you like.

Sol. 3: You can create multidimensional array, something like this:

```
$array[$position]['something']['value'];
```

And than use ksort function to sort array by keys. So, this is my idea.

Also, show exactly how you wana sort array. ( like input ( some data ) => output ( some data ) )

Comment: I flushed out the question please revisit it, expeicially Update 1

Answer (score 0):

Several variations whether you want to modify in place with a reference or return the new array:

```
function insert(&$array, $search, $value) {
    $i = 0;
    foreach($array as $k => $v) {
        if ($k === $search) {
            return array_splice($array, $i+1, 0, $value);
        }
        $i++;
    }
}

$a = array('foo' => 'bar', 'something' => 'value', 'apple' => 'sauce');
insert($a, 'something', 'new value');
```

Comment: I flushed out the question please revisit it, expeicially Update 1